# System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'System.Data.SQLite.DLL': (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007045A)

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, yaml, azure-powershell

Getting error: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'System.Data.SQLite.DLL': A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007045A)

The exe was being run through script in YAML pipeline. The DLL was placed in the same folder as exe

Answer (score 1):

> System.Data.SQLite require the appropriate version (e.g. 2005, 2008, 2010, 2012, 2013, 2015, 2017) of the Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library, to be successfully installed on the target machine, prior to making use of the executables contained therein.

Refer https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki and install appropriate setup of VC runtime.

Comment: you mean to add appropriate version of the Microsoft Visual C++ runtime library on YAML script?

Comment: No. Either install in the build agent vm or place the runtime dll along with System.Data.SQLite.DLL

Comment: Is it possible to use nuget command to install?

Comment: nuget is generally meant for dotnet project. So if you install here in your pipeline, you need to take care of the path and all

Comment: I copied msvcr120.dll, msvcp120.dll, msvcr100.dll and msvcp100.dll from C:\Windows\System32 in same folder as System.Data.SQLite.dll. But, it still throws same error

Comment: How did you decide on the version? It will depend on the flavour of System.Data.SQLite from https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

Answer (score 0):

Check which .NET framework / .NET Core runtime version System.Data.SQLite.DLL needs. It may be missing at the system and you must install it.